# What is this Magento open_basedir issue all about?

Tags: php, magento, open-basedir, php-ini

Running Magento with multiple stores. The base store works perfectly. On the secondary store when reaching checkout and the switch to https this set of warnings is generated:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect.     

File(/var/www/vhosts/mainstore.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/secondarystore.com/httpdocs:/tmp) in /var/www/vhosts/secondarystore.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 41

Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/mainstore.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/secondarystore.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 41

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/mainstore.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/secondarystore.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 41
```

phpinfo shows the following for open_basedir

```
local value : /var/www/vhosts/mainstore.com/httpdocs:/tmp
master value: none
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;DR; Go yell are the person administering your servers.

How'd you run the `php_info` function?  In the same PHP context as Magento, or by itself without bootstrapping Magento?  Under the same .htaccess and Apache (or alternative web-server) context as the URL for the sites that are throwing the errors, or under a different URL context?  Is your `https` setup using an identical apache configuration to your `http` setup?  The places to set a `php.ini` configuration value are legion.

1. Each domain you have may be using a different `php.ini` file.  The SSL and non-SSL versions of a domain are considered different domains
2. There are user specific [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files
3. Values can be set via `.htaccess` files
4. Values can be set via PHP at <a href="https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php>at runtime

PHP is yelling at you, most likely because your hosting company/IT guy has PHP's security features cranked to 11 for `https` URLs.  Chances are, even if you can locate where this is being set you can't change it without administrator rights, so find the person who knows how your server works and you'll find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I ran php_info from the same directory that Magento is in. I'd have to be yelling at myself here. Short story: everyone left me in this hole.